# Simple Trigger Is Not Created in Mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger, update

I'm creating a trigger in mysql, but even with the correct syntax and the query being accepted the trigger is not created. If anyone can help. The following is the sql:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER Data_entrada AFTER UPDATE ON scadabr.aux_Batelada FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   if OLD.flag_entrada=0 AND NEW.flag_entrada=1 THEN
    UPDATE scadabr.aux_Batelada SET dtEntrada=NOW() where idBatelada = 1;
end if;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is an English-language site, please post in English to ensure people can understand what you're asking. Alternatively, consider posting your question on the [Portuguese-language site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: FYI - As noted above, your direct communications on this site should be in English. However, many people do post code where the column and variables names are non-English. Don't try to rewrite those in English, as you may introduce typos and other issues not existing in your actual code.

Comment: What is the error message? _Qual é a mensagem de erro?_ Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/213235/edit) your question and add the message. _Por favor, [edite](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/213235/edit) sua pergunta e adicione a mensagem._

Comment: You change the delimiter to `$`, but don't use it anywhere.

Comment: If it is the new row that you want to update, use a before trigger. As @mustaccio points out, replace `END;` with `END$`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER Data_entrada AFTER UPDATE ON scadabr.aux_Batelada
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   if OLD.flag_entrada=0 AND NEW.flag_entrada=1 THEN
    UPDATE scadabr.aux_Batelada SET dtEntrada=NOW() where idBatelada = 1;
end if;
END;
```

-->

```
CREATE TRIGGER Data_entrada   BEFORE   UPDATE ON scadabr.aux_Batelada
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if OLD.flag_entrada=0 AND NEW.flag_entrada=1 THEN
        SET NEW.dtEntrada=NOW(), NEW.idBatelada = 1;
    end if;
END;
```

Comment: ??? What do you want to obtain when you change NEW pseudotable data in **AFTER** UPDATE trigger? all changes wiil be ignored. Rewrite the whole trigger and change the firing condition to BEFORE UPDATE.

Comment: @Akina - Good point.  Does my change look correct now?

Comment: Yes, now it is correct.